# Make dice values NOT repeat in if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like my dice values **not** to repeat because when it does, it registers a wrong input in my program (not a crash, simply a string message stating "Your input was wrong"). It is a board game so I do not want the same values to repeat, for example 6,0 to repeat twice or even thrice. Is there a way to save the dice values or anything I can do so that it chooses new random values every time?

```
dice = random.randint(0,3)
ans = network.receive()
    if dice == 0:
        guess = str(random.randint(0,4))+','+str(random.randint(0,4))
    elif dice == 1:
        guess = str(random.randint(0,4))+','+str(random.randint(4,9))
    elif dice == 2:
        guess = str(random.randint(4,9))+','+str(random.randint(0,4))
    else:
        guess = str(random.randint(4,9))+','+str(random.randint(4,9))
```

Desired output:

```
6,0
4,5
8,1
1,7
```

with **no** repeats, such as:

```
6,0
8,2
6,0 #this is a repeat, I do not want this to happen
3,9
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the combination (6,0) to repeat? Or do you not want any of those two dice rolls to repeat within one combination (that is, for instance, no (6,6) or (1,1))?

Comment: I do not want the (6,0) combination to repeat.

Comment: Why are you modelling dice if the values aren't allowed to repeat? Shouldn't this be card drawing or something?

Comment: @OrangeDog Good answer. But does that mean I will have to write down every possible combination `[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)...(9,9)]`? Because it will not be card drawing as I want numbers to repeat, but not a specific combination to repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could just roll over and over again until a new combination emerges. This also implies that you have to do some bookkeeping of the combinations already drawn. And you must make sure that there is at least one more possible combination left, otherwise the loop will not terminate.

```
combis = []

dice = random.randint(0,3)
ans = network.receive()

while True:
    if dice == 0:
        guess = str(random.randint(0,4))+','+str(random.randint(0,4))
    elif dice == 1:
        guess = str(random.randint(0,4))+','+str(random.randint(4,9))
    elif dice == 2:
        guess = str(random.randint(4,9))+','+str(random.randint(0,4))
    else:
        guess = str(random.randint(4,9))+','+str(random.randint(4,9))

    if not guess in combis:
        combis.append(guess)
        break
```

Comment: Wow! That is exactly what I was looking for and don't think I would have guessed the answer to be this simple. Thank you so much!!! I tested it several times and it did not repeat a combination once. Perfect!

Comment: Seemed like an impossible solution for a moment haha!

Comment: Yes! Just want to note for anyone viewing this question that to incorporate the `if ans==None` statement, it must be before `while True`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary that maps `dice` to arguments of `random.randint` calls:

```
>>> mapping = {
...     0: [0, 4, 0, 4],  # if dice == 1
...     1: [0, 4, 4, 9],  # elif dice == 2
...     2: [4, 9, 0, 4],  # elif dice == 3
... }
>>> mapping[0]
[0, 4, 0, 4]
>>> a, b, c, d = mapping[0]
>>> a
0
>>> b
4
>>> c
0
>>> d
4
```

Futher, using `collections.defaultdict`, you don't need to handle `else` case specially.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dice = random.randint(0, 3)
ans = network.receive()

dice_random_mapping = defaultdict(lambda: [4, 9, 4, 9], {  # else
    0: [0, 4, 0, 4],  # if dice == 1
    1: [0, 4, 4, 9],  # elif dice == 2
    2: [4, 9, 0, 4],  # elif dice == 3
})

if ans == None:
    start1, stop1, start2, stop2 = dice_random_mapping[dice]
    guess = str(random.randint(start1, stop1))+','+str(random.randint(start2, stop2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time to write this answer. Much appreciated! But unfortunately it still repeated values, such as repeated 4,4 in two instances, so the second 4,4 was a wrong input.

Comment: Please note that this is a bot vs. bot board game, so the program runs until someone wins. Therefore, my bot may repeat values, such as in the 4,4 instance. I want to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 2):

This function can do all dice rolling for you. It's slightly optimized.

```
import random

def roll_dice(low=1, high=6, count=1, allow_repeats=True):
    if not allow_repeats and count > (high - low):
        raise ValueError('Impossible not to have repeats with so many dice.')
    if not allow_repeats:
        possible_rolls = range(low, high) + [high]
        return random.sample(possible_rolls, count)
    return [random.randint(low, high) for _ in range(count)]
```

samples:

```
>>> roll_dice()
[1]
>>> roll_dice(count=2)
[5, 3]
>>> roll_dice(3, 10, count=2)
[8, 3]
>>> roll_dice(count=5, allow_repeats=False)
[6, 3, 2, 1, 4]
>>> roll_dice(count=5, allow_repeats=True)
[6, 6, 1, 5, 3]
```